# How to respond to "Delete" command from a macOS app in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstableview, first-responder

Let's say I created a `NSWindowController` which has a `NSTableview` with some elements.
I now try to make it possible to use the "Edit -> Delete" Menu bar option which is set by default to "First Responder -> delete:".
How do I implement this in my `NSWindowController` so my "delete" function in my `NSWindowController` is called and I can remove stuff (probably simply use the `NSTableview` selectedRows methods)?

I've tried to implement a function but the specific "Delete" element is disabled.

```
@objc func delete(sender: Any) {
    print("delete was pressed in the edit menu")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the method (note the underscore character)

```
@objc func delete(_ sender: Any) {
    print("delete was pressed in the edit menu")
}
```

Comment: And don't use `@objc func delete(_ sender: Any?)` which won't get called because its signature isn't correct (I assume).  `sender` is not an optional for the `firstResponder`' s `delete` method, near as I can tell.